# How to write jenkins plugin import last_successful_build artifact report to current build

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I wrote a plugin following

http://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-custom-plugin

And it generates a html report

```
            File artifactsDir = build.getArtifactsDir();
            String path = artifactsDir.getCanonicalPath() + REPORT_TEMPLATE_PATH;
            File reportFile = new File("path");
            // write report's text to the report's file
```

and for the next build, I want to import this report file to see the changes

I tried these but none of them works

```
build.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild().getArtifactManager().root() + REPORT_TEMPLATE_PATH
// fail with File not found, but the file is there in bash
build.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild().getArtifactsDir() + REPORT_TEMPLATE_PATH
// null pointer exception, seems to be generated by getArtifactsDir()
build.getPreviousBuild().getArtifactManager().root() + REPORT_TEMPLATE_PATH
```

So how can I obtain the last successful build report file within current build ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in an pipeline job. I stripped parts of the original code, I hope I didn't introduce an error. I also removed error handling for clarity:

```groovy
// find last successful build
def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()
while (lastSuccessfulBuild && (lastSuccessfulBuild.currentResult != 'SUCCESS')) {
    lastSuccessfulBuild = lastSuccessfulBuild.getPreviousBuild()
}

// here I go for a file named 'crc.txt'
// this works only if you have a
// archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'crc.txt', fingerprint: true
// somewhere in your build
def build = lastSuccessfulBuild?.getRawBuild()
def artifact = build.getArtifacts().find { it.fileName == 'crc.txt' }
def uri = build.artifactManager.root().child(artifact.relativePath).toURI()
def content = uri.toURL().text
```

When I compare our solutions: you don't use `child()` and you have the relative path in `REPORT_TEMPLATE_PATH` while I obtain it from the artifact.